# what's the equivalent class of java.awt.Image and java.awt.image.PixelGrabber in Android?

Tags: android

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.awt.image.PixelGrabber
```

**What's the equivalent class of `java.awt.Image` in Android?**

I have to use  `import java.awt.*;` `import java.awt.image.*;`pakage class in my android app, but I am not able to do this and does anyone knows that how to do this in Android or what's the equivalent class of `java.awt.Image`  and `java.awt.image.PixelGrabber` in Android?

Comment: Did you find the java.awt.image.PixelGrabber alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Android has its own mobile UI framework, so you won't find any AWT or Swing classes in it.

The closest to what you want is probably the `android.graphics.Bitmap` class.